# Fastest way to compare each item in array with rest of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

I have an array of items, and for each of the item in the array, I need to do some check against the rest of the items in the same array.

Here is the code I am using:

```
const myArray = [ ...some stuff ];

let currentItem;
let nextItem;
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  currentItem = myArray[i];
  for (let j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    nextItem = myArray[j];
    doSomeComparision(currentItem, nextItem);
  }
}
```

While this works, I need to find a more efficient algorithm because it slows down significantly if the array is very big.

Can someone provide some advice on how to make this algorithm better?

#### Edit 1

I apologize.

I should have provided more context around what I am trying to do here.
I am using the loop above with a `HalfEdge` data structure, a.k.a. DCEL.

Basically, a HalfEdge is an object with 3 properties:

```
class HalfEdge = {
  head: // some (x,y,z) coords
  tail: // some (x,y,z) coords
  twin: // reference to another HalfEdge
}
```

A `twin` of a given `HalfEdge` is defined like so:

```
/**
  * if two Half-Edges are twins:
  * Edge A   TAIL ----> HEAD
  *           =          =
  * Edge B   HEAD <---- TAIL
  */
```

My array contains many `HalfEdges`, and for each `HalfEdge` in the array, I want to find its twin (i.e., one that satisfies the condition above).

Basically, I am comparing two 3D vectors (one from `currentItem`, the other from `nextItem`).

#### Edit 2

Fixed typo in code example (i.e., from `let j = 0` to `let j = i + 1`)

Comment: This is probably more appropriate on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: can you add more information on which items are you comparing, without more information you cannot get farther from generic comparisson

Comment: If you're comparison is symmetric - ie doSomeComparision(a, b) === doSomeComparision(b, a), you can save some work by setting j = i + 1 -  `for (let j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {`
`

Comment: @devlincarnate this code might be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on CR except `myArray` would need to be properly defined so the code could be run and a better explanation of what this code does would need to be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a linear-time solution to your problem. I am not that familiar with javascript, so I'll feel more comfortable about giving you the algorithm correctly in psuedo-code.

```
lookup := hashtable()
for i .. myArray.length
  twin_id := lookup[myArray[i].tail, myArray[i].head]
  if twin_id != null
    myArray[i].twin := twin_id
    myArray[twin_id].twin := i
  else
    lookup[myArray[i].head, myArray[i].tail] = i
```

The idea is to construct a hash table of `(head, tail)` pairs, and to check if a `(tail, head)` pair already exists that matches the current node's. If so, they are twins, and mark them as such, otherwise update the hash table with a new entry. Every element is looped over exactly once, and insertion / retrieval from the hash table is done in constant time.

Comment: I tried this approach and it worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more information about the type of items

1) You should first sort your array, aftewards the comparisson can be done forward only, it should then give you a complexity of o(log n) + n^2, this could be useful depending on the type of your items and could lead to more improvements.

2) Starting the internal loop from i + 1 should reduce it further to o(log n + n)

```
const myArray = [ ...some stuff ].sort((a,b) => sortingComparison(a,b)); // sorting comparison must return a number

let currentItem;
let nextItem;
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  currentItem = myArray[i];
  for (let j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    nextItem = myArray[j];
    doSomeComparision(currentItem, nextItem);
  }
}
```

Bonus:
Here is some fancy functional code (if you are aiming for raw performance the for loops versions are faster)

```
function compare(value, array) {
  array.forEach((nextValue) => {
    // Do your coparisson here
    // nextValue === value
  }
}

const myArray = [items]
myArray
  .sort((a,b) => (a-b))
  .forEach((v, idx) => compare(v, myArray.slice(idx, myArray.length))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! As commented on the other response below, the j = 0 was a typo on my part. I am essentially comparing two 3D vectors at the end of the day, do you think I should still do some kind of sorting?

Comment: what do you mean by 3d vectors? can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether there's any kind of specific algorithm that is more efficient, but the following optimizations come to my mind immediately:

- Let j start with i+1 - otherwise you are comparing all items twice
  against each other
  <strike>- Initialize a variable with myArray.length outside
  the loops as the same operation is done twice.</strike>
- If the comparison
  is any kind of direct 'equal / larger' then it could help to sort the
  array first

**Update on Edit 1**
I think the optimization depends on the number of expected matches. I.e., if all HalfEdge objects have a twin, then I think you're current approach with the changes above is already pretty optimal.
However, if the percentage of expected twins is rather low, then I would suggest the following:
- Extract a list of all heads and a list of all tails, sort them, and compare against each other. Remember which heads have found a twin tail.
Then, do you original loops again, but only enter the inner loop for the heads which found a match.
Not sure this is optimal, but I hope you get my approach.

Comment: myArray.length is not computed right? it is a property, so performance wise it shouldn't have much of an impact

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am actually already starting j with j + 1. My bad for totally missing that out in my code example. Regarding sorting the array first, do you think I should still sort my array when I am basically comparing two 3D vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Since values are 3D coordinates, build an octree ( O(N) ) and add items on their HEAD values. Then from each of them, follow them to their TAIL values using already built octree ( O(N*k*log(N)) ) with its nodes containing maximum of k edges which means only k comparisons at the lowest level nodes of each TAIL. Also finding each TAIL may need traveling up to log(N) levels of octree from top to bottom.

O(N) with constant of building octree + O(N * k * log(N)) with low enough k edges per node(and logN levels of octree).

When you follow a TAIL in octree, any HEAD with same value would be in same node with maximum k elements or any  "close enough" HEAD value would be inside that lowest level node and its closest neighbors.

Are you looking for an exact HEAD==TAIL or some tolerance is used? Tolerance could need "loose octree" imo.

If each edge has a length defined, then you can constrain the search radius by this value, if edges are both ways symmetric.

For up to 5k - 10k edges, there may be only 5-10 levels in octree depending on edges per node limit and if this limit is picked to be around 2-4 then each HEAD would need to do only 10-40 operations to find its twin edge with same TAIL value.